# Group Rows in HTML Table from PHP Array

Tags: php, html, arrays

Assume I have this array from a query results:

```
[0]=> { ["category"]=> "fruit" ["value"]=> "banana"} 
[1]=> { ["category"]=> "fruit" ["value"]=> "grape"}
[2]=> { ["category"]=> "fruit" ["value"]=> "pineapple"}    
[3]=> { ["category"]=> "animal" ["value"]=> "mouse"}    
[4]=> { ["category"]=> "animal" ["value"]=> "elephant"}    
[5]=> { ["category"]=> "animal" ["value"]=> "ant"}
```

How to make an HTML table which same group shows only once and make `td rowspan`value in group field(`category`) according to number of members?

Desired result:

```
--------------------
|fruit   |banana   |
|        -----------
|        |grape    |
|        -----------
|        |pinapple |
--------------------
|animal  |mouse    |
|        -----------
|        |elephant |
|        -----------
|        |ant      |
---------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a different array.

```
$truecats = array();
foreach ($cats as $pieces) {
    if (!isset($truecats[$pieces['category']]) {
        $truecats[$pieces['category']] = array();
    }
    $truecats[$pieces['category']][] = $pieces['value'];
}

// You can then loop over this array:

foreach ($truecats as $name => $values) {
   echo "<tr><td rowspan=" . count($values) . ">$name</td>";
   foreach ($values as $val) {
      echo "<td>$val</td>";
   }
}
```

Comment: For second and next member we need adding new row (`tr`)